# Is it possible to create a recursive sum in ms access by sql query or vba

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

i have table like>>

```
Parent_ID   -   Acc_ID   -   Value
   0           1             0
   1           13            1
   13          121           1
   121         121001        1

   0           2             0
   2           23            1
   23          131           1
   131         131001        1
```

The output I want

```
Parent_ID   -   Acc_ID   -   Value
   0           1             3
   1           13            3
   13          121           2
   121         121001        1

   0           2             3
   2           23            3
   23          131           2
   131         131001        1
```

What I want is unlimeted Calculating of all the Nodes of the Accounts tree

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2e6fpecvv7q0boy/Database41.accdb?dl=0      -    This my database. I created a query that tells what I want, but I used dsum function, but I feel that it is unprofessional and it is limited. I want an unlimited account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow @HASAN. If you were working with a full RDBMS, I'd be recommending the use of Recursive CTEs to achieve this. Unfortunately these aren't supported in MS Access. So instead I'd recommend using a recursive VBA function. Below you'll find two versions of what I cam up with. The improved  version (V2) is presented first. It avoids the use of a DLookup and should run somewhat faster (though it will still be slow).

Improved Version:

```
Function SumChildValuesV2(MyValue As Long, RecordID as Long)

    Dim TheSum As Long
    TheSum = MyValue
   
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM TheTable WHERE ParentID = " & RecordID)
    
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do Until rs.EOF
            TheSum = TheSum + SumChildValuesV2(rs!Value, rs!AccountID)
        rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    SumChildValuesV2 = TheSum
    
End Function
```

Unimproved Version:

```
Function SumChildValues(RecordID As Long)
        
    Dim MyValue As Long
    MyValue = 0
        
    MyValue = DLookup("[Value]", "TheTable", "[AccountID]=" & RecordID)
    
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM TheTable WHERE ParentID = " & RecordID)
    
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do Until rs.EOF
            MyValue = MyValue + SumChildValues(rs!AccountID)
        rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    SumChildValues = MyValue
    
    
End Function
```

Enter this into a VBA code module in MS Access, with whatever modifications are necessary for your real data (for example if your IDs are strings not integers you'll need to surround them in quotes, and obviously you have table and field names to update).

In your query you then simply want something like:

Improved Version:

```
SELECT
   TheTable.ParentID,
   TheTable.AccountID,
   SumChildValuesV2(Value, [AccountID]) AS TotalValue
FROM TheTable;
```

Unimproved Version:

```
SELECT
   TheTable.ParentID,
   TheTable.AccountID,
   SumChildValues([AccountID]) AS TotalValue
FROM TheTable;
```

Comment: Steve Lovell   thank you very much. It worked like a chameleon. Really you are a genius. Thank you so much again

Comment: A nice solution, but the problem is that this solution is very slow. I mean, I have large data. When I activated the query, it took almost a minute. Is there another solution through MS access exclusively? Thank you.

Comment: I may be able to improve it a little, but I think it will remain rather slow. If you could upgrade to a full RDBMS as the backend database you'd get some better options. In the meantime, see the answers to the other question that this one "duplicates".

Comment: I've just updated my answer. The new code doesn't include the use of the DLookup function and so should run faster, though I'd still expect it to be rather slow.

Comment: @HASAN, I'd appreciate your feedback on this improved solution, including details of how much more efficient this is with your large dataset. It's not perfect, but given that you're using MS Access, I think that's out of the question.